# Scripting with Scapy

Tags: python, linux, unicode, scapy

I am trying to write a script, using Scapy (packet manipulation tool), that will change the packets, using the following code:

```
def sendCommand(self):
    src = self.srcAdd.toPlainText()
    dst = self.destAdd.toPlainText() #getting strings from textedits
    pay = self.payload.toPlainText()
    print(src + dst + pay) #testing line
    command = IP(dst=dst, src=src)/ICMP()/pay #line giving error
```

I used extra variables for testing purposes, e.g. the "csrc" and "cpay"

All the line marked `#testing` line work fine

Here is the error I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MainDriverScapy.py", line 30, in createCommand
command = IP(dst=dst,src=src)/ICMP()/pay
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 271, in __div__
return other.__rdiv__(self)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '__rdiv__'
```

It seems not to be inserting the variable in to the given field in the Scapy command.

Comment: I have never used Scapy but for me it looks like your `src` or `dst` or `pay`have wrong encoding. Did you tried some different one than unicode?

Comment: Wait a minute... Why do you try divide some IP/ICMP object by some text? Okay, from what I can see [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html) your pay needs to be some sort of string - please chceck if some other encoding for pay works.

Comment: @MaLiN2223 it's not maths, it's a Scapy command for merging the IP and ICMP protocols together.

Comment: @MaLiN2223 I tried both IP(dst="{}",src="{}")/ICMP()/"{}".format(dst,src,pay) and IP(dst="%s",src="%s")/ICMP()/"%s" % (dst,src,pay) and got the same error again, both times

Comment: The `__rdiv__` method is used to implement the binary arithmetic operations like `+`, `-`, `/`, etc with reflected (swapped) operands. It is only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands types differ. Since the error message says the 'unicode' object, it must mean that one of the operands/subexpressions in the expression `IP(dst=dst, src=src)/ICMP()/pay` is a unicode string and at least one of the others is not. It doesn't make sense to divide a string by a number or a number by a string, so try converting whichever one it is to an `int`.

Comment: What does your #testing line print?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, turns out the toPlainText method leaves the text in an unusual encoding that scapy can't understand so I converted it to a string using the str() method.

```
c = str(self.srcAdd.toPlainText())
dst = str(self.destAdd.toPlainText()) #getting strings from textedits
pay = str(self.payload.toPlainText())
```